# Are these linear programming constraints correct?

Tags: linear-programming

The problem is: Beth works a maximum of $20$ hours/week programming computers and tutoring math. She receives $\$25$/hour for programming and $\$20$/hour for tutoring. She works between $3$ and $8$ hours/week programming, but always gives more time to tutoring. How many hours should she work at each job to maximize her income?

Let $x$ = # hours programming and $y$ = # hours tutoring.

My constraints are:

> Total hours: $x + y ≤ 20$
>
> Hours programming: $3 ≤ x ≤ 8$
>
> Hours tutoring: $y > x$

Are these right?

Comment: Seems OK. I would be more comfortable with $y\ge x$, even though it goes against the usual meaning of "more".

Comment: But then y could be equal to x, and y is always greater.

Comment: Sure. But if you are ultimately solving "graphically," and the relevant corner involves the line $y=x$, we probably would not reject that as an answer.

Comment: But if I'm solving graphically, I would use the vertices, no? So it wouldn't matter if the line was y ≥ x or y > x since it would be the same line.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, though "between" is a bit ambiguous. Sometimes, it is meant the way that you interpreted it, but sometimes, it is meant to indicate *strict* inequalities.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what the restriction says, because x and y do not have to add up, only if she has to maximize her income.

Comment: I think it's meant the way I interpreted it; I wouldn't worry.

Comment: You're correct. I've deleted it from my answer.

Comment: Okay, sounds good.  Thanks so much for your quick answer!

Comment: If it were meant the other way, we actually *couldn't* maximize income, so I'm sure you appropriately interpreted it.

Comment: What exactly is the other way?

Comment: The other way would (in this context) be $3<x<8$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's my way :)